# Integrate Child with Parent Components using React & Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

So the requirement is to decouple as much as possible so that on deleting any integrated child components, the Parent won't crash. The idea is to create Parent component with root saga middleware having Headers, footers, side bars, does the authentication and authorization and runs the root sagas. The parent Component will integrate external independent Child components/projects which has its own set of Sagas and Api calls.

**What I want to achieve** To decouple the following and create `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` in separate projects and finally integrate them in `Parent` project as a `plugin` or a `library` but again these `plugins` or `libraries`
will have its own Saga and Api calls.

**Reason to decouple** The company has over 30+ new projects and all these are being handled by different developers. Hence we are trying to integrate all the 30+ project to the `Parent` project with an intention that if the one project breaks, the others will continue to run and also the `Parent` won't need to adjust itself if we integrate or delete any child components like in the following structure, if we remove `ChildOne` component, the project will break as the path i.e., `"../components/store/childone/saga"` will be invalid.

I wonder if this can be achieved using `injectReducer({ key: 'cartContainer', reducer }) & injectSaga({ key: 'cartContainer', saga });` but again If you can provide an idea on how to use this and where to use this either on `Parent` or `Children` and how to integrate all the `children` with the `Parent`

I am quite new to the React World so I'd appreciate your feedback Thank you..

The Current project has the following structure.

RootSaga.js

```
import ParentSaga from "../components/store/parent/saga"
import ChildOneSaga from "../components/store/childone/saga"
import ChildTwoSaga from "../components/store/childtwo/saga"

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield spawn([
    ParentSaga(),
    ChildOneSaga(),
    ChildTwoSaga()
  ])
}
```

Here is an example of routes.js

```
import Parent from "../components/parent/index"
import ChildOne from "../components/childOne/index"
import ChildTwo from "../components/childOne/index""

const Routes = [

  { path: "/", component: Parent },
  { path: "/child-one", component: ChildOne },
  { path: "/child-two", component: ChildTwo }
```

And this is my index.js

```
import rootReducer from "./reducers"
import rootSaga from "./sagas"
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
)
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a *direct* answer to your question:

First, it looks like the Redux code you're writing there is very outdated.  You *should* be using our official Redux Toolkit package to write Redux logic, rather than the deprecated original `createStore` API and handwritten reducer logic.

We have been recommending *against* use of sagas in almost all cases for years now. This is even more true today - RTK Query solves the data fetching use case, and the new RTK "listener" middleware does basically everything sagas can with a simpler API, smaller bundle size, and better TS support.

Please see these docs pages and posts for more details:

- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware
- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/06/presentations-modern-redux-rtk/
- https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/

And finally, we also have a docs page on managing code splitting:

- https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting

Comment: As per the documentation ```configureStore``` automatically adds the ```thunk middleware```. How about ```Saga Middleware```? Re-writing the entire project in ```Thunk``` is out of scope.

Comment: In fact all the users are recommending to use ```Saga``` and one such article is https://betterprogramming.pub/refactoring-from-redux-thunk-to-redux-saga-f9379a172a99, Why the Redux community doesn't add both ```thunk``` and ```Saga``` to the ```ConfigureStore```.

Comment: Well, those "users" don't maintain Redux :) We specifically think that sagas are over-complicated and lead to code that is hard to understand. They also don't work well with TypeScript: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/02/blogged-answers-why-redux-toolkit-uses-thunks-for-async-logic/ .  I'm not saying you must rewrite the entire app right now : ) But I _would_ specifically recommend evaluating the RTK listener middleware to see if it solves the use cases you have in your app, and consider using it instead of sagas going forward.

Comment: ```takeEvery``` ```takeLatest``` ```yeild.delay()```. Does thunk has all these.

Comment: Thunks don't do _any_ of those.  However, the "listener" middleware _does_ have equivalents of all those in some form - see the API docs I linked above.